# How to fix this question:ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: command: /usr/bin/python /usr/local/

Tags: python, linux, pyqt5

- Python:3.7
- Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
- Pip：latest

I cant install Pyqt5 by "pip install PyQt5" or "pip3 install PyQt5"

```
" Using cached PyQt5-5.15.4.tar.gz (3.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmp12utc_07
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-isn1q135/pyqt5_3ec1cc0700174738991a9fc21489ab73
    Complete output (37 lines):
    Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
    /usr/bin/qmake -query
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 126, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
    AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
        main()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 131, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        config_settings)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 159, in _get_wheel_metadata_from_wheel
        whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-9qtio6u7/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sipbuild/api.py", line 51, in build_wheel
        project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('pep517')
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-9qtio6u7/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sipbuild/abstract_project.py", line 83, in bootstrap
        project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-9qtio6u7/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 481, in setup
        self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "project.py", line 63, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-9qtio6u7/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtbuild/project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
        super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-9qtio6u7/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 227, in apply_user_defaults
        self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-9qtio6u7/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 75, in apply_user_defaults
        self._get_qt_configuration()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-9qtio6u7/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyqtbuild/builder.py", line 484, in _get_qt_configuration
        for line in project.read_command_pipe([self.qmake, '-query']):
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-9qtio6u7/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sipbuild/project.py", line 445, in read_command_pipe
        "'{0}' failed returning {1}".format(cmd, pipe.returncode))
    sipbuild.exceptions.UserException
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8e/a4/d5e4bf99dd50134c88b95e926d7b81aad2473b47fde5e3e4eac2c69a8942/PyQt5-5.15.4.tar.gz#sha256=2a69597e0dd11caabe75fae133feca66387819fc9bc050f547e5551bce97e5be (from https://pypi.org/simple/pyqt5/) (requires-python:>=3.6). Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmp12utc_07 Check the logs for full command output.
```

I dont kown how to do ...

Comment: I do not recommend installing pyqt5 using pip in RPi since PyQt does not provide the binaries for that architecture so you will have to compile it manually (and that is what pip tries) and that also implies installing Qt manually. Better to use the pyqt5 provided by the OS: `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5`